# gallian's contemporary abstract Algebra exercises

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, self-learning

i have just  finished doing **A first course in abstract algebra by John Fraleigh (group theory only)** and now i am looking forward to **apply** all the stuff i learnt by doing problems.

i have on my mind *Gallian's Contemporary abstract Algebra* ****, because it contains many problems in the exercises.

*My Problems while doing Gallian's Contemporary abstract Algebra exercises :*

1. almost half of problems dont have any solution and
2. i dont have any access to teachers

I need suggestion here on being able to complete the exercises of gallian.what can assist me apart from asking doubts on stackexchange(which i want to be minimize) ?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Group-Theory-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486459160 is a good alternative. It has LOTS of problems and complete solutions. It's also very cheap, and I'm sure that you can find it on the internet somewhere in Russia...

Comment: @ChrisDugale ok thank you